# How to check for null in javascript object using $.each?

Tags: jquery, json

I need to find a more efficient way to reach into a javascript object, find null values and replace them with empty strings (or other content).  This is what I have, and it functions, but I need a more efficient methodology and I just know there must be one using $.each but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is what works...  I want to replace all those if statements with something more elegant?

```
        var oMilestone = {
            sTitle: $(this).attr("ows_Title"),
            sStatus: $(this).attr("ows_Status"),
            sOwner: $(this).attr("ows_Assigned_x0020_Owner"),
            sStart: SPConvertDate($(this).attr("ows_Start_x0020_Date")),
            sDue: SPConvertDate($(this).attr("ows_Due_x0020_Date")),
            sPercent: $(this).attr("ows_Percent_x0020_Complete"),
            sComments: $(this).attr("ows_Update_x0020_Comments")
        }
        if (oMilestone.sOwner == null) {
            oMilestone.sOwner = " "
        }
        if (oMilestone.sStart == null) {
            oMilestone.sStart = " "
        }
        if (oMilestone.sDue == null) {
            oMilestone.sDue = " "
        }
        if (oMilestone.sPercent == null) {
            oMilestone.sPercent = " "
        }
        if (oMilestone.sComments == null) {
            oMilestone.sComments = " "
        }
```

Any help?

Kevin

Comment: Those values can't be null, `.attr()` will return either a string or `undefined`..

Answer (score 0):

Use `for...in` to iterate over the properties. See below,

```
for (i in oMilestone) {
   if (oMilestone.hasOwnProperty(i) && !oMilestone[i]) {
        oMilestone[i] = " "; //covers undefined, null and ""
   } 
}
```

Comment: This affects prototype properties as well

Comment: undefined, null, false, 0, "", NaN

Comment: @Asad Thanks.. corrected. mm was going to delete mine.. but seems like you deleted yours.

Answer (score 0):

My answer doesn't use the `$.each`.

But you can always just write a little helper function inline, which will have access to $(this) already.
Saves repeating yourself.

```
function attrOrDefault(attribute) {
    return $(this).attr("ows_Title") || " ";
}

var oMilestone = {
    sTitle: attrOrDefault("ows_Title"),
    sStatus: attrOrDefault("ows_Status"),
    sOwner: attrOrDefault("ows_Assigned_x0020_Owner"),
    sStart: SPConvertDate($(this).attr("ows_Start_x0020_Date")),
    sDue: SPConvertDate($(this).attr("ows_Due_x0020_Date")),
    sPercent: attrOrDefault("ows_Percent_x0020_Complete"),
    sComments: attrOrDefault("ows_Update_x0020_Comments")
}
```

Or if you think you will use this often, then maybe extend jQuery to possess this function?

```
$.fn.attrOrDefault = function(attribute) {
    return this.attr("ows_Title") || " ";
}
```

Comment: Another option along those same lines is `...sTitle: $(this).attr("ows_Title") || " ",...`

Comment: @KevinB   ooooo I like it; not done it like that before.  I have updated my answer to use the one-line version.  Does that look right to you?

Comment: Yes, assuming `this` is a jQuery object (which it would be in your case, i missed the fact that you made it a plugin)